# difference on a column between two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

There are two dataframes

Dataframe 1

```
`name   hits1` 
 google  100
```

Dataframe 2

```
name hits2
google 80
```

i need to find the difference between both the hits1 and hits 2 based on name, any suggestions please.

output should be

```
name   hits1 hits2 diff_hits
google. 100   80     20
```

Comment: Share some sample data

Comment: please post a sample for each of your dataframes, and perhaps a desired output

Comment: Add example please

Comment: Apologies , added now.

Comment: Define "difference"? Different values of other columns for the same `domain_name`, different `domain_name`, different row counts for the same `domain_name`?

Comment: Also please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: final two dataframes look as above , and it is different values of the same domain_name from two different dataframes.

Comment: Are the two data frames guaranteed to be of the same shape with respect to Name & hits?

Comment: yes and other catch is there may be some of the names existing in one dataframe and not other .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
# Sample Data
dt1 = {'name':['google', 'xyz', 'abc'],'hits1':[100, 50, 10]}
dt2 = {'name':['def', 'xyz', 'google'],'hits2':[25, 75, 45]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dt1)
df1.set_index('name', drop=True, inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dt2)
df2.set_index('name', drop=True, inplace=True)

# Create a New df with the difference column added
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
df3['Diff'] = df3.apply(lambda row: abs(row['hits1'] - row['hits2']), axis=1)
```

Starting with:

```
    hits1
name    
google  100
xyz 50
abc 10
```

and

```
    hits2
name    
def 25
xyz 75
google  45
```

The result is:

```
    hits1   hits2   Diff
name            
abc 10.0    0.0 10.0
def 0.0 25.0    25.0
google  100.0   45.0    55.0
xyz 50.0    75.0    25.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick thing, i did the similar fashion but ended up not resulting the data properly .

hits_pct_diff = round((athena_lgcy_metric["hits"] - athena_aws_metric["hits"])/athena_lgcy_metric["hits"] * 100, 2)